# Is there a way to use the values of a one query as arguments in another query at the same time with apollo client?

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-js

I'm using apollo client with NextJS with 2 queries.
The first query gets a list of cases where each case has a unique **id**.
The second query fetches a list of case comments using the **id** from each case in the previous query.

I could simply modify the schema to resolve the case comment for each case, but I don't have access to it so that's out of the answers.

I don't know how to go about that with apollo client and would be pleased to be assisted.

Comment: Can you show the GraphQL schema you're trying to access?

Comment: @ThisaruG , I don't have access to the schema. I'm on the frontend.

Comment: How are you going to write a GraphQL client without having access to the schema? It is impossible to do so. Either you have to have the schema, or you have introspection access to the GraphQL service. Either way, you have to have the access to the schema to write a client.